# dispose button over chart

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm using c#, winform, ihave a panel, i created from code a chart and a button that is positioned over the chart, both are inside the panel, when i click on the button i have to clear all the series in chart, and i have to dispose the chart and the button, how can i do this?

this is the code i use in the load event

```
        foreach (var item in panel1.Controls)
        {
            if(item is Button)
            {
                Button item1 = (Button)item;
                item1.Click += new EventHandler(dispose);
            }
        }
```

delegate

```
    public void dispose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;            
        chart.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put the controls in an array,the panels controls property refreshes and breaks the forloop
this disposes all controls within the panel

```
Foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls.ToArray())
{
    item.dispose();
}
```